# Separate woocommerce variable products on archive page

Tags: variables, woocommerce, product

Is there a way to show woocommerce product variations separately on the product category, search or another archive page? For example, if there are red t-shirt and yellow t-shirt variations it should display 2 products on 't-shirt' search result page.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, no you cannot. There is an [idea](http://ideas.woothemes.com/forums/133476-woocommerce/suggestions/6399974-show-product-variations-on-shop-page) for this and you can lend your voice in support of it.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already resolved it myself. :)

Comment: Can you share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
    <?php
```

/**
* woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
*
* @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
* @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
*/

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>

</a>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php
```

/**
* ADD PRODUCT VARIABLE WITH ADD TO CART ON CATALOG PAGE
ADDED BY GW
**/
    ?>

```
<div class="catbox">

<?php
```

//ADD SHORT DESCRIPTION TO PRODUCT
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 5); ?>

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

<?php
```

//ADD VARIATIONS BEFORE ADD TO CART

```
if($product->product_type == "variable"){
woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
} else {
woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();
}

?>
```